Looking up Solidity custom errors for a third party contract
I am getting a revert from a third party Solidity smart contract:
Revert reason: execution reverted: custom error 0x142bddf5

What is the best way to map these custom error codes to something human readable?

You can use Swiss Knife online tool:
Example:

